# How do I request a refund on Fandango?

Tags: fandango

I want to request a refund for a ticket order on Fandango, as I can't make the show time.

According to [Fandango's FAQ](https://www.fandango.com/Help?Category=RefundsAndExchanges&Question=2), you can request to exchange or refund movie tickets up until the posted showtime, but the instructions on *how* to request a refund are frustratingly vague.

**How do I request a refund for movie tickets on Fandango?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Sign in](https://www.fandango.com/account/signin) to your Fandango VIP account you used to make the order.

   - If you purchased tickets as a guest, create a Fandango account with the same email address you used to order the tickets.
2. Open your [Purchase History](https://www.fandango.com/account/mypurchases). (*My VIP Account → See Purchase History*)

   [image: My VIP Account > See Purchase History]
3. Find the order you want to refund and click *Can't make the show?*

   [image: Purchase History > Can't make the show?]
4. Choose if you want to request a cash refund (minus convenience fee) or exchange for Fandango credit.
5. Select a reason for refunding and click Continue.